# ESP8266 and ATmega328 UART communication, gets() function

Tags: c, uart, esp8266, atmega328p

I'm trying to get an ATmega328 and an ESP8266 to talk to each other over UART.

In the attached minimal example, I have an LED on pin 16 (B2) that should start on and do a slow blink to show data was sent / received.  However, it seems to hang on the gets() call, as the LED never comes back on.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define F_CPU 16000000
#define BAUD 115200

void init_uart() {
    // UART setup
    uint16_t ubbr_value = F_CPU / (16UL*BAUD) - 1;
    UBRR0H = (uint8_t) (ubbr_value >> 8);
    UBRR0L = (uint8_t) ubbr_value;
    UCSR0B = (1 << RXEN0)  | (1 << TXEN0);
    UCSR0C = (1 << UCSZ01) | (1 << UCSZ00);
    // Status LED on pin 16.
    DDRB |= (1<<DDB2);
}

void transmit(char c) {
    // Wait for the flag to say we're good to write to the data register.
    while(!(UCSR0A & (1 << UDRE0)));
    UDR0 = c;
}

char receive() {
    // Wait for the Rx flag to say we've received a message.
    while(!(UCSR0A & (1 << RXC0)));
    return UDR0;
}

FILE uart_output = FDEV_SETUP_STREAM(transmit, NULL, _FDEV_SETUP_WRITE);
FILE uart_input = FDEV_SETUP_STREAM(NULL, receive, _FDEV_SETUP_READ);

int main(void) {
    init_uart();
    stdout = &uart_output;
    stdin  = &uart_input;

    PORTB=0xff;         // Comms LED on
    _delay_ms(1000);    // Makes sure LED on/off isn't too fast to see.

    puts("AT");         // Send AT command to ESP8266
    PORTB=0x00;         // After command sent, turn LED off to show where we get stuck
    _delay_ms(1000);    

    char input[64];
    gets(input);        // Get a response from the ESP8266

    PORTB=0xff;         // Turn LED back on if successful (Never reaches here)
}
```

Using the same circuit/code, the LED comes back on if I use an FT232 to send a string from the terminal to the ATmega.  I can also get the **OK** response from the ESP8266 if I send an **AT** command to it.

I'm probably doing something incalculably stupid, but it looks as though I'm not able to use the gets() function to receive from the ESP8266.

I originally assumed it must be something to do with the line endings, but from what I gather puts() sends the carriage return / line feed required by the ESP8266 anyway.

Comment: Do you have a debugger, to check it step by step?

Comment: I actually have an Atmel ICE on its way, but sadly it's not here yet..  Perhaps I'll be able to update with an answer in a few days!

Comment: Your code shows a blocking receive function, but does not even try to read from stdin until long after any expected reply is probably concluded.  To capture data sent *before* you even call `gets()` you would need to have a serial receive interrupt service routine which copied data from the UART to a buffer for the input stream.  It is not obvious that your code sets up or enables such an ISR.

Comment: Please note that the `gets` function was removed from the C language many years ago.

Comment: What happens if you remove `_delay_ms(1000);` after `puts("AT");`? If you still don't receive anything try sending some other `AT` command which's response has more characters to see if you can 'catch' at least some of them. And it is better to use something as `if(fgets(input, sizeof input - 1, stdin) != (void*)0) {}` than `gets()` to avoid buffer overflow.